# Connecting from VM to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, virtualbox

I'm having trouble connecting to a MySQL database on my host OS (Win 7) from my Oracle VirtualBox running Ubuntu. I wrote this php code in order to connect but I keep receiving an error connecting:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=192.168.1.9;dbname=finance';
$db_username = 'sdb_user';
$db_password = 'password';

try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        include('../errors/database_error.php');
        exit();
    }

     $query = 'SELECT * FROM books';
     $books = $db->query($query);

     foreach ($books as $book)  {
         echo $book['title'];
     }

?>
```

I know the code works, because I can get it to run from my Windows 7 host OS using localhost instead of the IP address, and I know that both Linux on VirtualBox and Windows 7 are on the same subnet because I can successfully ping the other from each side.

I'm fairly certain that I opened port 3306 correctly on the windows side also, but I have no idea how to check if that's the problem or not.

What else should I be doing to get the code to connect to the MySQL db?

EDIT: The problem was that the port was not open for remote connections. After I opened the port I got the error message stating I was not allowed to connect to the sql server. From there I created a new user on the Windows MySQL with the username "home" and password "home" and was able to connect to it using:

```
$ mysql -h 192.168.1.9 -u home -p
```

However, when I run my file, which now reads:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=192.168.1.9;dbname=finance';
$db_username = 'home';
$db_password = 'home';
```

I still get the 'database error'
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to check avaliablility of your MySQL from VB, using `nmap` and `mysql` from command line

Comment: From your Linux box `telnet 192.168.1.9 3306` should show if 3306 is open and if MySQL is listening

Comment: @machavity I think this might be the problem. When I do it from VB it times out, but when I run netstat from windows command prompt, it shows up as listening. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: in response to my last comment: when I set up my inbound rule in Windows firewall, I initially had it set to local port 3306 and remote port 3306. Switching the remote port to the "all ports" setting in the properties dialog box fixed the issue.